# Java create .docx file from byte array

Tags: java

I read a .docx file to byte array, but when I tried to save it again to .docx file, the file couldn't open.

Can anyone explain why?

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    byte[] data = readFile("test.docx");
    System.out.println(data.length);

    try (FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream("testCopy.docx")) {
        fos.write(data);
    }
}
```

And here is readFile method

```
public static byte[] readFile(String filePath) throws FileNotFoundException, IOException {
    File file = new File(filePath);
    byte[] bytes = new byte[(int) file.length()];
    try (DataInputStream dataInputStream = new DataInputStream(new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(filePath)))) {
        dataInputStream.readFully(bytes);
    }

    return bytes;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should probably look into the difference between DataInputStream and FileInputStream.

Try using FileInputStream instead of DataInputStream and see how it works.

```
try (FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(filePath)) {
            fileInputStream.read(bytes);
}
```

Comment: @Ibrahim also, it's probably a good idea to initialize bytes array this way: byte[] bytes = new byte[fileInputStream.available()]; From the docs: "Returns an estimate of the number of remaining bytes that can be read"